# How to add a hover over effect on a button when user hovers over the button's parent container?

Tags: jquery, css

https://codepen.io/nisofwareengineer/pen/jONLWxw

What I am trying to acheive:

Normally, when you hover over a button, there is an hovered over effect where the color of the button slightly changes.

I want this **effect to be applied when the user hovers over the parent div** of this button.

In this case the divs with classes ''serviceContent'' are the parents divs. Inside these parent divs are the buttons. These are the blue buttons which say ''Find out more''

So far, I have tried using this:

```
$('.serviceContent').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).find('.btn').trigger('mouseover')
})
```

It doesn't seem to work - is there something else that can be triggered which will give the same effect as if the user hovers over the button?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".serviceContent").mouseover(function(){
$("button").addClass("button-hover");
});
$(".serviceContent").mouseout(function(){
$("button").removeClass("button-hover");
});
});
```

Add class in css `.button-hover{color: red;}`

Answer (score 0):

Just use the below given css to hover child elements
css:

```
#bestServiceBike:hover .btn.btn-primary{
  background-color:#2639ff;
}
.serviceContent:hover .btn.btn-primary{
  background-color:#2639ff;
  color:#fff;
}
```

check out this fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/vn6txgyc/